# rails routing duplicates path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a simple enough problem of taking a rails 2 route and making it working with rails 4.  The rails 2 version is this:

```
map.token '/sessions/token', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'token'
```

I've changed it to:

```
get '/sessions/token', to: 'sessions#token', as: '/token'
```

for rails 4.  The problem is when I go to `/sessions/token` it immediately redirects to `/sessions/token/sessions/token` and gives a 404

I added `byebug` to the token method but the request never makes it there before redirecting.  I added it early in the application controller but I reach a point where the next function just stops working.

The log produces this when requesting https://delete-me.domain.org/sessions/token:

```
[delete-me] Started GET "/sessions/token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-02 05:44:27 -0500
[delete-me] Processing by SessionsController#token as HTML
[delete-me] Redirected to http://delete-me.domain.org/sessions/token/sessions/token
[delete-me] Filter chain halted as :ensure_proper_protocol rendered or redirected
[delete-me] Completed 302 Found in 114ms (ActiveRecord: 5.8ms)
```

I think it gives the `:ensure_proper_protocol error` because it redirects to `http` from `https`.  I don't know why it does that.  Maybe someone has had a similar problem and they can enlighten me.

Comment: the redirection has to do with this line of code in sessions_controller.rb:  

<<<< ssl_allowed  :destroy, :index  if USE_SSL >>>>

if I comment it out things work...

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :sessions do
   get :token, on: :collection #-> /sessions/token (sessions#token controller action)
end
```

Comment: thanks...still have the same problem after trying this, though :(

Comment: [jc] Processing by SessionsController#token as HTML
[jc] Redirected to http://jc.net.org/sessions/token/sessions/token
[jc] Filter chain halted as :ensure_proper_protocol rendered or redirected
[jc] Completed 302 Found in 75ms (ActiveRecord: 10.3ms)
[jc] Started GET "/sessions/token/sessions/token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-20 22
:37:52 +0700
[jc] 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sessions/token/sessions
/token"):

Comment: I traced the redirection to this line in sessions_controller.rb:

`code`ssl_allowed :destroy, :index if USE_SSL

Comment: Looks like you're redirecting inside the controller action, is this the case?

Comment: Oh okay - what is that? You're using SSL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92882/discussion-between-craig-and-rich-peck).